# GCP Deployment manager error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to use the project creation template which is on github, even after changing the appropriate values in config.yaml I am getting following error.

location: /deployments/projectcreation000/manifests/manifest-1534790908361
  message: 'Manifest expansion encountered the following errors: Error compiling Python code: No module named apis Resource: project.py Resource: config'

you can find the repo link here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/project_creation

Please help as I need it for production workflow. I have tried "sudo pip install apis" in Cloud Shell but it does not help, even after successful installation of apis module.

Comment: I suspect you've not followed the instructions as summarized in the `README`. Have you updated the values in `config.yaml`? DM can be challenging to debug but you may wish to try the `--preview` flag on your deployment. If you're confident you've done everything correctly, then you're best bet is to file an issue against the DM samples repro directly because the code's authors will see it (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues)

Comment: yes I have updated the values in config.yaml. The issue seems to be in the python file.

Comment: I eye-balled it but didn't see anything obvious `project.py` references `apis.py` and that includes `ApiResourceName` which is the source of your error. If there weren't so much setup, I'd try to repro this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The apis module in this context [refers to](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/project_creation/apis.py),
not a pip package. Ensure you have all the files in the same relative paths to each other when deploying these samples.

Comment: If this is the same [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/223), you may try the following for the next troubleshooting steps: 1.Make sure to have correct permissions on <project#>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
2.Permission changes can take up to 20min to propagate as per [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/project_creation/README.md)
3.Can you give your project a different, incredibly specific name that is guaranteed not to clash with any existing projects?

Answer (score 0):

you either need to fix the import or move the file, so that `apis.py` will be found.